# ARM32 Position Independent Code binary offset

Tags: gcc, arm, gnu

I'm working on a ARM bare metal binary, and I'm trying to get a fully position independent binary. Everything is working fine except global variables. Here's my code:

```
int foo = 1;
int main() {
   return &foo;
}
```

And I'm compiling it with something like:

```
$(ARMCC)-gcc -fpic -mcpu=cortex-a7 main.c -o main.o
$(ARMCC)-ld main.o main.o -T linker.ld -o main.elf
$(ARMCC)-objcopy -O binary main.elf main.bin
```

```
OUTPUT_FORMAT("elf32-littlearm", "elf32-littlearm", "elf32-littlearm")
OUTPUT_ARCH(arm)
ENTRY(_start)

SECTIONS {
    . = ALIGN(4);
    .text : {
        _text_start = .;
        *(.text)
        _text_end = .;
    }

    /* Read only data */
    . = ALIGN(4);
    .rodata : {
        _rodata_start = .;
        *(.rodata)
        _rodata_end = .;
    }

    /* BSS, Block starting symbol */
    . = ALIGN(4);
    .bss : {
        _bss_start = .;
        *(.bss)
        _bss_end = .;
    }

    /* Regular data */
    . = ALIGN(4);
    .data : {
        _data_start = .;
        *(.data)
        _data_end = .;
    }
}
```

(this isn't complete, but enough for an explanation)

main() returns something like 0x100, which is the offset from the start of the binary, instead of the absolute address of `foo`.

I know C/Arm Assembly well, but I'm no good with linkers. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

flash.s

```
ldr sp,=0x1000
bl fun
b .
```

main.c

```
unsigned int x=5;
unsigned int *fun ( void )
{
    return &x;
}
```

flash.ld

```
MEMORY
{
    one   : ORIGIN = 0x00002000, LENGTH = 0x1000
    two   : ORIGIN = 0x00003000, LENGTH = 0x1000
    three : ORIGIN = 0x00004000, LENGTH = 0x1000
    four  : ORIGIN = 0x00005000, LENGTH = 0x1000
}
SECTIONS
{
    .text   : { *(.text*)   } > one    
    .rodata : { *(.rodata*) } > two    
    .bss    : { *(.bss*)    } > three  
    .data   : { *(.data*)   } > four   
}
```

build

```
arm-linux-gnueabi-as --warn --fatal-warnings -mcpu=cortex-a7 flash.s -o flash.o
arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc -fpic -Wall -O2 -ffreestanding -mcpu=cortex-a7 -c main.c -o main.o
arm-linux-gnueabi-ld -nostdlib -nostartfiles -T flash.ld flash.o main.o -o main.elf
arm-linux-gnueabi-objdump -D main.elf > main.list
arm-linux-gnueabi-objcopy --srec-forceS3 main.elf -O srec main.srec
arm-linux-gnueabi-objcopy -O binary main.elf main.bin
```

examine

```
Disassembly of section .text:

00002000 <fun-0xc>:
    2000:   e3a0da01    mov sp, #4096   ; 0x1000
    2004:   eb000000    bl  200c <fun>
    2008:   eafffffe    b   2008 <fun-0x4>

0000200c <fun>:
    200c:   e59f300c    ldr r3, [pc, #12]   ; 2020 <fun+0x14>
    2010:   e59f200c    ldr r2, [pc, #12]   ; 2024 <fun+0x18>
    2014:   e08f3003    add r3, pc, r3
    2018:   e7930002    ldr r0, [r3, r2]
    201c:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
    2020:   00002fe8    andeq   r2, r0, r8, ror #31
    2024:   00000000    andeq   r0, r0, r0

Disassembly of section .data:

00005000 <x>:
    5000:   00000005    andeq   r0, r0, r5

Disassembly of section .got:

00005004 <.got>:
    5004:   00005000    andeq   r5, r0, r0
```

in detail

```
0000200c <fun>:
    load the offset to got into r3
    200c:   e59f300c    ldr r3, [pc, #12]   ; 2020 <fun+0x14>
    load the offset of x in the got into r2
    2010:   e59f200c    ldr r2, [pc, #12]   ; 2024 <fun+0x18>
    compute the address to the address of x
    2014:   e08f3003    add r3, pc, r3
    load the address of x into r0
    2018:   e7930002    ldr r0, [r3, r2]
    return the address of x
    201c:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
    2020:   00002fe8    andeq   r2, r0, r8, ror #31
    2024:   00000000    andeq   r0, r0, r0
```

Using your linker script

```
Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <_text_start>:
   0:   e3a0da01    mov sp, #4096   ; 0x1000
   4:   eb000000    bl  c <fun>
   8:   eafffffe    b   8 <_text_start+0x8>

0000000c <fun>:
   c:   e59f300c    ldr r3, [pc, #12]   ; 20 <fun+0x14>
  10:   e59f200c    ldr r2, [pc, #12]   ; 24 <fun+0x18>
  14:   e08f3003    add r3, pc, r3
  18:   e7930002    ldr r0, [r3, r2]
  1c:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
  20:   00000010    andeq   r0, r0, r0, lsl r0
  24:   00000000    andeq   r0, r0, r0

Disassembly of section .data:

00000028 <x>:
  28:   00000005    andeq   r0, r0, r5

Disassembly of section .got:

0000002c <.got>:
  2c:   00000028    andeq   r0, r0, r8, lsr #32
```

the address of x is 0x28 and that is what it returns.   Now depending on how you optimized and whatever else is in your program can make 0x100 the answer.

Comment: since you didnt define any addresses apparently the linker is starting at 0 so 0x100 is both the the address from the beginning which is also the....address of foo

Comment: Wouldn't that make it address dependent though? My program has to be loaded completely in allocated memory.

Comment: if you want to load in a different place, then you need to adjust the entries in the global offset table, that is its purpose.  and you can see the relative addressing of .text to the got needs to be fixed..   the address of each global has an entry in the got and every access has the extra instructions and loads to get that address.   So that you can load things in different places

Comment: Other toolchains do it differently, but you can see that with these command lines at least this is how it works for gnu.

Comment: I've got everything sorted out, thanks for the help